# How can I get more citizens to educate themselves?

Tags: tropico-4

I noticed that I have too many uneducated citizens. While a small minority of them go to high school and college to get educated on their own, is there a way to attract more students? I pay a fortune to get foreign educated workers, while my island's population is too lazy to study!

Comment: Do you have open student slots in your schools? Have you enacted social security?

Comment: Yes both active :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the number of jobs that require high school or college education, and make sure they pay more than the uneducated jobs. Beyond that, it takes time.

Comment: Well, I usually open a "Rum Distillery" and I have too many empty slots, that's why I asked. Is there any edict that will allow me to have more educated workers?

Comment: I don't believe so. When I need more educated workers, generally I turn to immigration. The immigration office has a mode that attracts more educated immigrants. Additionally, having more people than jobs will lead to more people seeking education, as well.

Comment: I believe Literacy Program makes Tropicans more likely to go to school. If not, it definitely increases the rate they increase in skills so they'll graduate sooner.

Comment: It increases the rate all tropicans increase in all skills. It does not affect the rate at which they go to school.

Answer (score 4):

According to my personal experience and [this thread](http://forum.kalypsomedia.com/showthread.php?tid=16487), Tropicans with high Intelligence are more likely to go to High School or College. (It's factored into the "do I educate myself?" equation.)

So, if you have empty education-required jobs, and those jobs pay well enough to tempt a normal Tropican, and nobody's volunteering for education, then give up on the current generation and educate the next one: set your Grade Schools to *Spelling Bee Contests* to get the largest possible boost in Intelligence for your young graduates.

One of the *other* ideas in that thread I linked is to start a eugenics program: simply **ensure** that only highly-intelligent people are living on Tropico. (Children have the same qualities as their parents, so intelligent parents make for intelligent children.) Your military and secret police probably have some good ideas on how to arrange that. While you're at it, you can **select** for low courage, to keep rebellions down.

Answer (score 1):

Tropicans are more likely to attend High School/College if there are actually jobs for them requiring that level of education and those jobs are better than the uneducated ones. If you're constantly importing workers, there will never be any educated jobs available. Stop importing workers, leave some well paying high school jobs open and you'll soon have students.